# In-App Messaging

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, modal

We are implementing in-app messaging and are facing the following issues / questions:

a. After pushing the in-app message from a Journey, when we open the app for the first time, the in-app message does not display. Once we background the app and then re-open it a 2nd time, only then is the in-app message display.

Why is this behaviour in contradiction to what the documentation says that the in-app messages will be downloaded in the background and displayed the very next time the app is opened?

b. We configured the in-app message to be of modal type with a single button. The expectation was that message will be displayed continuously until and unless the user dismisses it by pressing the dismiss button or the cross (X) symbol.

But again we are observing that the message gets dismissed automatically within a few moments even without the user having touched the dismiss button or cross (x).

Why is this so ? How to make the modal message stay continuously ?

c. We could not find the character length for the in-app message title and body mentioned anywhere in SF documentation. So please let us know the character length limits.

Answer (score 3):

Glad to hear you're implementing InApp Messages!

A) This is expected, at least partially.  There is a silent push delivered to the device which will tell the SDK there is new content to fetch.  This data is also fetched when your application is foregrounded.  In the case where your device has not fetched the data before a foreground event, the data will be fetched and subsequently will be shown on the next app launch.  Net-net-net: patience is a virtue.

B) If you believe that you have not configured your modals to auto-dismiss, but they are, in fact, auto-dismissing then you should open an investigation through your AE.  I suspect the message has been configured to auto-dismiss as this is one of the things we test during UA testing. (ref. [InApp Messages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_mp_inapp_messages.htm&type=5))

UPDATE
C) Only the [ImageFill template](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_rn_march_2020_mp_inapp_image_fill.htm&type=5) has restrictions on title and body length.  Those are 25 and 90 characters respectively.

Comment: Thanks Bill for your response!

A. How to ensure that a silent push is always delivered to the SDK whenever our journey sends out an in-app message to the users. The in-app message getting displayed on the very subsequent app open by the user is a mandatory requirement from business so we cannot have the app fetch the new content on being foregrounded and then the in-app message being displayed on the next app.
Please let us know how to make this work ? Is the "QuietPushEnabled" parameter of the SDK payload determine whether the silent push is delivered or not in the background ?

Comment: B. As far as I recall I did not come across any setting during the configuration of the in-app message that makes the modals to auto-dismiss. Can you please let me know how to check that ?
Or better still now that you have access to our account, can you please review the in-app message and let me know if thats the case or not ?
If its not then you need to investigate why the expected behaviour is not seen.

Comment: C. Does "ImageFill" template refer to an in-app message with an embedded image ?

Comment: First, I do not have access to your account and you can not grant it "here" :)  If you need support beyond what has already been answered here then you should open a support case through your AE.

A-A: Patience is a virtue -- and you need to think about this in terms of real world application.  It's only testers that are creating messages and then chomping at the bit to get them viewed. In the real world you could be sending me a message right now and I'd download it in the background just as you'd expect ;)  Open a support case.

Comment: Thank you for actually following through and opening a support case @MichaelMoreno.  My team and I are looking into your issue.